# Как запомнить первый операнд и сложить к второму в калькуляторе

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в калькуляторе первый операнд запоминался и перезаписывался вторым. Чтобы запоминался я, вроде как, сделал, а вот как сделать, чтобы сложить их вместе - не совсем понимаю.

```
<input type="button" value="7" onclick="calculator.answer.value += input.value;rememberFirstOperand();" />

function rememberFirstOperand()
    {   
        var rep1 = /[/|*|+|-]/;//проверка на наличие операнда в строке input
        var rep2 = /[0-9](?=[*|/|+|-])/;//проверка что знак в конце первого операнда

        var tempValue = 0;


        if (rep1.test(calculator.answer.value) && rep2.test(calculator.answer.value))
        {   
            tempValue=calculator.answer.value;
            calculator.answer.value='';//очищаю для ввода второго элемента

        }

    }
```

Comment: И я второй раз утверждаю, что сделай Вы калькулятор нормально: https://habrahabr.ru/post/50196/ , все было бы просто

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/kcLuvoco/2/

```js
//Буфер можно в спрятанное поле или data-buffer запихать
var buffer;
var sign = '';
var doit = document.getElementById("doit");
doit.onclick = function(){
 var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
  var input = answer.value.match(/(\d+)([-+/*]?)/);
  var newValue = parseInt(input[1]);
  switch(input[2]){
   case '+':
    case '-':
    case '/':
    case '*':
     buffer = newValue;
      sign = input[2];
      break;
    default:
     if(sign==''){
       alert('incorrect sentence');
        return;
      }
      //Можно через exec. Но я его не люблю!
      switch(sign){
      case '+':
       answer.value = buffer+newValue;
        break;
      case '-':
       answer.value = buffer-newValue;
        break;
      case '/':
       //не забываем про 0
       answer.value = buffer/newValue;
        break;
      case '*':
       answer.value = buffer*newValue;
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="answer" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="rememberedValue" />
<div id="numpad">
  <button type="button" id="doit">
    do it!
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня калькулятор работает чуть не так как нужно,тоесть вводится вся строка с первым операндом знаком и вторым операндом,а нужно что бы я ввел к примеру '1234+' и второй операнд '3432432 и нажал ='

Comment: Поправил код, чтобы он считывал, как вы пишете. О_о
например, введите  

    111/ doit! 3 doit!  

должно получиться 37